# App Engine Connected Android Project fails to register, even in debug mode

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm, gae-eclipse-plugin

I've done this before and never had a problem.  I'm using a different computer now - the main difference being that it's XP instead of W7 and I just can't seem to get this to work.

I make a new project, debug it as a local app engine connected android app.  Try to register and I get an error saying "Internal Server Error" in the debugger.  Now, I know that there is an issue with the auth cookie, but I think that's only in release mode, not in local development mode.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Eclipse Indigo for Java EE developers
Install Android ADT
Install Google Plugin 2.3
Install Google Plugin 2.4 Beta
Configure Google Plugin to use 2.3, not 2.4
Create project, run, and it should register

Seems that the 2.4 plugin isn't working independently.  See Google group here:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/e8139c6dcd9f1aa7/19663737a5b2fb00?lnk=raot&pli=1